# cannot compile matrix to pdf

Tags: amsmath, matrices, mathtools, preamble

I have a problem knitting my rmd to pdf. I have tried copying the code that works for others from this forum but it is not working for me. I keep receiving:

!LaTeX Error: Can be used only in preamble.
Can anyone please help?

### `title: "Untitled" output: pdf_document: latex_engine: xelatex`

```
library("tinytex")
```

`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{amsmath} 
\begin{document}

\[
\begin{bmatrix}
    x_{11}       & x_{12} & x_{13} & \dots & x_{1n} \\
    x_{21}       & x_{22} & x_{23} & \dots & x_{2n} \\
    \hdotsfor{5} \\
    x_{d1}       & x_{d2} & x_{d3} & \dots & x_{dn}
\end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix}
    x_{11} & x_{12} & x_{13} & \dots  & x_{1n} \\
    x_{21} & x_{22} & x_{23} & \dots  & x_{2n} \\
    \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
    x_{d1} & x_{d2} & x_{d3} & \dots  & x_{dn}
\end{bmatrix}
\]
\end{document}
```

Thanks for replying to my issue. However, I still can't sort out the problem myself. Hence I have attached the log file for your perusal.
[Unt.log](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1NOXstfa2i4A-IFLI4Q0BZxGvcc8T1uQe/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Your code runs fine on MikTeX. I think the problem is due to TinyTeX. As said on its website "you cannot really compile any LaTeX documents, but it contains the most important utility tlmgr (TeX Live Manager)". I can't figure out the exact problem, most probably you need to install the packages manually. But you may use overleaf if you have a problem with installing the packages manually or any standard TeX distribution.

Comment: It worked OK when I used `pdflatex` but using `xelatex` was told that the file `mathtools.sty` could not be found.

Comment: @PeterWilson In my case, both `pdflatex` and `xelatex` provided same output.

Comment: @PeterWilson something strange with your installation as pdftex and xetex have (mostly) the same tex input tree.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I'm not surprised. I was told to install `xelatex` by `sudo apt-get install texlive-xetex`. I never used `xe---` before this as it doesn't fit with my normal working practice and I probably won't try it again. BTW `lualatex` processed the file correctly.

Comment: @PeterWilson oh so I guess you have two  texlive systems on your path the linux-packaged one (with xetex) and a vanilla tug one (with pdftex) , that can lead to interesting effects.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Hi, I have attached the log file. Do you mind giving it a look?

Comment: That log is not generated by the code you posted, it uses microtype which the posted code does not use and it has `\documentclass` on line 69